# Why are two threads calculating slower than one?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-cores

I am working on a benchmarking application made with Java.  I run this code twice on the main thread and then once in two individual threads:

```
if (testing == null) {
    testing = new byte[TEST_SIZE][TEST_SIZE][TEST_SIZE];
}

for (int x = 0; x < TEST_SIZE; x ++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < TEST_SIZE; y ++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < TEST_SIZE; z ++) {
            testing[x][y][z] = (byte)RANDOM.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
}

if (finished == Test.LOOP_COUNT - 1) {
    testing = null;
}
```

The task on the main thread is completed much more quickly than the two threads, as shown in the output of the application:

```
Starting test Array Handling with a single core.
Loop #1 finished in 1.820588011 seconds.
Loop #2 finished in 1.779667175 seconds.
Finished in 3 seconds.
Starting test Array Handling with multiple cores.
Loop #2 finished in 9.433253526 seconds.
Loop #1 finished in 9.465652985 seconds.
Finished in 9 seconds.
```

I read something somewhere that stated two threads running really fast operations would not perform as well as a single thread, but that two threads working on more demanding operations outperformed the single thread.  I didn't think this was the case because the each loop is quite demanding.  The only reason I can think of is the threads are not actually running on their own cores.  Could this be the problem?  I have a 2 core 4 thread Intel Core i7-3537U.

**EDIT:**

Test class:

```
package net.jibini.park.tests;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author zgoethel12
 */
public abstract class Test {

public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
public static final int LOOP_COUNT = 2;

public static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Test> tests = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Test>();

public int finished = 0;
public int longestTime = 0;
public double timeSum = 0;

static {
    RANDOM.setSeed(481923);
    tests.add(new TestArray());
}

public abstract String getName();

public void runTest(final boolean multithread) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finished = 0;
                longestTime = 0;
                timeSum = 0;

                if (multithread) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; i ++) {
                        final int f = i;
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                doLoop(f + 1);
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; i ++) {
                        doLoop(i + 1);
                    }
                }

                while (finished < LOOP_COUNT) {
                    System.out.print("");
                }

                System.out.println("Finished in " + (multithread ? longestTime : (int)timeSum) + " seconds.");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
    }).start();

}

public void doLoop(int id) {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    doTest(id);
    handleLoopFinish(id, start);

}

public abstract void doTest(int id);

public void handleLoopFinish(int id, long start) {

    long current = System.nanoTime();
    long difference = current - start;
    double seconds = (double)difference / 1000000000;
    if (seconds > longestTime) {
        longestTime = (int)seconds;
    }
    timeSum += seconds;
    System.out.println("Loop #" + id + " finished in " + seconds + " seconds.");
    finished ++;

}

}
```

Array Test:

```
package net.jibini.park.tests;

/**
 *
 * @author zgoethel12
 */
public class TestArray extends Test {

public static final int TEST_SIZE = 512;

byte[][][] testing = null;

@Override
public void doTest(int id) {

    if (testing == null) {
        testing = new byte[TEST_SIZE][TEST_SIZE][TEST_SIZE];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < TEST_SIZE; x ++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < TEST_SIZE; y ++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < TEST_SIZE; z ++) {
                testing[x][y][z] = (byte)RANDOM.nextInt(100);
            }
        }
    }

    if (finished == Test.LOOP_COUNT - 1) {
        testing = null;
    }

}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "Array Handling";
}

}
```

Comment: Show your multithreaded code. If you used the same, but fired it on each thread, then the threads must have fighted for the right to write to the same object in RAM - that was the delay

Comment: it's quite likely that your benchmark is simply wrong, e.g. by neglecting warmup, try using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and see if you still get those results.

Comment: How did you split the job between the two threads?

Comment: Your `TestArray` and `Test` classes seem to have a lot of _dead code_ (i.e. variables not actually used) which can simply be eliminated by the JIT compliler. As @the8472 suggest, for reliable micro-benchmarks, you're better off using a good framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use just one `RANDOM` object. I'm afraid this is shared between the two threads, which could make them really slow.

Try to use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

Comment: Actually, I'm working in Java 6 so I just created new instances.

Comment: You should really consider upgrading, especially if you want to have better performance - a lot of small changes in the JVM internals can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Starting up a second thread, depending on what library that you select to perform multithreading, takes a lot of overhead, and the operation that you seem to be doing, depending on how large TEST_SIZE is, is likely very efficiently performed by one CPU because you traverse the array in memory in a contiguous fashion.

I've been instructed in coursework that the built-in Thread Java library has much more overhead than say the ForkJoin framework, so maybe you'll get more expected results using that library.

As a resource, here's a nice website that I used in my concurrency class:
http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/teachingMaterials/spac/grossmanSPAC_forkJoinFramework.html

Be careful to do warm up runs, as said below. They are pivotal in making sure that you can see the benefits. We tried to do ~100 runs, with ~10 as warm up, to make sure you get some good averages. Averaging across many runs helps a lot due to context switching/other computer processes that may add variability to your trials!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I need to have the threads as part of the benchmarking, and putting the value of `TEST_SIZE` too high results in running out of memory.  I have dedicated 6 GB to it.  I will look into ForkJoin.

Comment: The problem was using the single instance of Random.  I fixed it, and the time needed to process was about halved.